# No sound in headphone, intel sound card

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

EDIT: I solve the problem via turn on all the alsamixer settings.
(MM to 00)

I'm a noob and I am new to ubuntu. I installed ubuntu and I found that sof-bin is required and I installed it. After installing sof-bin, it still cannot solve the problem.

The dummy output is disappeared, and I want the headphones to work(the headphone output).

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
(Ubuntu desktop)

From command `alsamixer`:

Card: sof-essx8336
Chip: Intel Kabylake HDMI

From command `sudo dmesg | grep audio`:

```
[    0.018653] software IO TLB: area num 8.
[    0.801004] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.801005] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x000000008936f000-0x000000008d36f000] (64MB)
[    3.820947] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    3.821025] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.821223] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    4.082941] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.089622] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    4.103274] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: NHLT_DEVICE_I2S detected, ssp_mask 0x1
[    4.103278] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Overriding topology with MCLK mask 0x1 from NHLT
[    4.103279] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
[    4.104327] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    4.104329] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    4.104332] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[    4.204118] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    4.204122] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    4.207734] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk mask 0x1a0
[    4.207736] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk SSP0
[    4.207737] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk DMIC enabled
[    4.207738] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk headphone GPIO enabled
[    4.207739] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: quirk headset at mic1 port enabled
[    4.208525] sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    4.208677] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
[    4.328551] input: sof-essx8336 Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input13
[    4.328632] input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input14
[    4.328692] input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=6 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input15
[    4.328741] input: sof-essx8336 HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sof-essx8336/sound/card0/input16
```

From command `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 149
    Memory at b121c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at b122d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
```

Any help? I just don't want to swap back Windows anytime I need to get audio works. (I like linux more than windows)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added some information, hope it is useful